# Auth_User v/s User table in Django

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am learning Django, and i am following the Django tutorials in the djangoproject website. I wanted to use the Django Auth. In the tutorial I saw a reference to a User table which will get created automatically during the 'migrate' if I have all the needed settings. I made sure all the settings are inside the settings.py file and ran migrate. I saw that instead of User table, it is Auth_User got created inside the database. I want to hash the password before storing it in the database, for that I tried using set_password function, which is not available with the Auth_User.

Can any one please tell me the difference between Auth_User and User

Comment: The table name gets prefixed by the package that creates it so this is normal. What do you mean "the difference between `Auth_User` and `User`"? Where did you see a `User` table? Or do you mean the `User` model?

Comment: `auth` is the namespace (app) Its unclear what you're asking about

Answer (score 3):

Methods are defined on the model class, not on the database table. The User class creates a table called "auth_user", because it is inside the auth app. And the `set_password` method *is* available on that model.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is coming from the fact that `User` is a class of the `auth` app.

As seen in the Django documentation, the app name is prepended to the start of the table name:

> For example, if you have an app bookstore (as created by manage.py
>   startapp bookstore), a model defined as class Book will have a
>   database table named bookstore_book